# Firestore converting DateTime to TimeStamp

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When adding data to `firestore`, the database converting `DateTime` object to `TimeStamp`
My code:

```
class JobApplication {
  DateTime time;
JobApplication({this.time});

JobApplication.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)
  : time = map['time'] as DateTime;

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
return {
  'time': this.time,};
}
```

when fetching it showing following error

```
Expected a value of type 'DateTime', but got one of type 'Timestamp'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> file:///home/koha/Projects/sirajulhuda_app/lib/screens/job_appli_screen.dart:56:24
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 212:49      throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 60:3        castError
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 442:10  cast
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/types.dart 411:9        as
packages/sirajulhuda_app/models/job_application.dart 72:26                        fromMap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the TimeStamp that you get from Firestore to DateTime.

Like this:

```
Timestamp timestamp = // What you get from FireStore
DateTime date = timeStamp.toDate();
```

EDIT

```
class JobApplication {
  DateTime time;
 JobApplication({this.time});

JobApplication.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)
  : time = (map['time'] as Timestamp).toDate();

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
  return {
    'time': this.time,};
}
```

Comment: I've edited the question. If i'm fetching as `stream`, how to convert the `time` from `JobApplication` model?

Comment: I've Edited my answer. Just cast your data as Timestamp and convert this Timestamp with toDate()